# API OpenWeather, В каком формате даются данные?

Tags: c#

Я подключил api openweather. Вот в sunrise и sunset. Что это за данные? Как их преобразовать в время? c#

```
{
  "lat": 52.2297,
  "lon": 21.0122,
  "timezone": "Europe/Warsaw",
  "timezone_offset": 3600,
  "data": [
    {
      "dt": 1645888976,
      "sunrise": 1645853361,
      "sunset": 1645891727,
      "temp": 279.13,
      "feels_like": 276.44,
      "pressure": 1029,
      "humidity": 64,
      "dew_point": 272.88,
      "uvi": 0.06,
      "clouds": 0,
      "visibility": 10000,
      "wind_speed": 3.6,
      "wind_deg": 340,
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 800,
          "main": "Clear",
          "description": "clear sky",
          "icon": "01d"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Comment: А документация API что говорит? )

Comment: UNIX Time Stamp

Comment: Какой (де)сериализатор JSON используете? Скорее всего, в нём можно задать распознавание такого типа.